# How to get GL, G0 from "GL=>G0" using Ruby Regular Expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I have following string:

```
"xxxxx  GL=>G0   yyyyyy  "
```

I want to extract GL and G0 using ruby regular expression.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is rather vague. Do you want to pull out key/value pairs when separated by => ?

The following regexp may suit your needs:

```
matches = /.*(\w{2})=>(\w{2}).*/.match("xxxxxx GL=>G0 yyyyy ")
puts matches[1] // GL
puts matches[2] // G0
```

This assumes that your key/values are 2 characters long separated by a => sign. It does not permit spaces between the characters and the => sign. Let me know if this is what you need. Otherwise, provide a more detailed description of what strings you may need to parse.